# change dot value to 0. value

Tags: javascript

In some of my javascript calc, I want to change the value like this:

```
Value = 3.075

Result =
3
0.075
0.005
```

Now I use 
`value.toString().split(".")[1]` and it return `075` , not `0.075`

Comment: Why on earth would it return 0.075, you just split the string on periods, and you're expecting to get a period ?

Comment: Where does the "3  0" come from?  Where does the "0.005" come from?

Comment: @idlerboris - what a great edit, you just made a multiline variable, which is invalid ?

Comment: @idlerboris This should not have been accepted as an edit. You just made his semi-valid code 100% invalid.

Comment: @adeneo that's exactly how the original was, idlerboris only spaced it in to show as code. The original contains line breaks but without being spaced in as code, so SO doesn't show them.

Comment: @MrCode -  That could be the case, but that still makes the edit show invalid code, while the original didn't

Comment: @adeneo, I only help to show code in question for user, who probably don't know how it is working. The question about "why Mg Linn have this code in his question" must be ask for author - not me.

Comment: And, of course, this is not 100% clear question - and comment of dcromley is good. Let's wait answer of author

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [Number.prototype.toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) and the modulo operator.

First take `3.075 % 1` and receive `0.07500000000000018` because of float errors.
Then do `.toFixed(3)` to convert it into a fixed precision string.

```
(3.075 % 1).toFixed(3)
>> "0.075"
```

Same for getting the `0.005`

```
parseFloat((3.075 % 0.01).toFixed(3))
>> 0.005
```

Comment: I just have to say, great answer, it makes absolutely no sense, but I love the use of the modulus, but not enough jQuery.

Comment: Thank you  TheShellfishMeme

Comment: What, are you PSYCHIC? How were you able to get the gist of the question? Good answer. +1

Comment: I work as a developer. I receive much more cryptic requirements on a daily basis. @dcromley